# Erro na pesquisa no DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, vba

Olá, eu tenho um Textbox em que inserido um nome automaticamente faz a pesquisa em um DataGridView com dados dos funcionários, por exemplo se eu digitar a letra "a" irá aparecer todos os nomes que comecem com a letra "a", mas se o DataGridView não tiver nenhum nome com a letra "a", o sistema da erro.

Gostaria de saber se tem um código que faça não dar erro, que quando não achar nenhum nome com a letra correspondente, não feche o programa

O código que uso no textbox para fazer a pesquisa é esse:

```
FuncionariosBindingSource.Filter = "nome like'%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Para resolver este erro faça o mesmo que fiz abaixo na imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
qualquer coisa me chama no zap 3199650-8625

Comment: Seu código deu certo, era o que eu precisava.
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! Estou desenvolvendo um programa de Gestão para a empresa onde trabalho, a empresa tem um sistema de gestão não muito bom, estou refazendo ele em vb.net, gostaria de auxiliar, irá ganhar muito conhecimento com isso? Se sim entre em contato 31 99650-8625